# How to retrieve a business object from DevExpress SearchLookUpEdit?

Tags: c#, devexpress, xtragrid

I need to retrieve a business object from a DevExpress SearchLookUpEdit when the control is bound to a collection of custom objects.

I can get the currently selected row object via GetSelectedDataRow or FocusedRow in the GridView but I don't need the currently focused/selected row, I want to find the row and retrieve the row myself by supplying a criteria, either an index or the EditValue.

How is this done? SearchLookUpEdit do not have the GetRowByKeyValue method that is in LookUpEdit.

Comment: Have you tried iterating the collection?.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the `searchLookUpEdit1View.GetFocusedRow()` method.
Please note, that this method will only work if the dropdown window was expanded.  Otherwise, the only solution is to obtain the editor's EditValue property and find the corresponding object in the DataSource.